# Linux, нет доступа в директорию

Tags: linux

Есть каталог с правами `2660`, `root:test`. Добавил пользователя в группу `test`. В директорию зайти не могу. Но, когда ставлю на нее права `2670` - работает.

Для чего мне права на выполнение, чтобы просто прочитать содержимое? Неужели Sgid всему виной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Относительно директорий, `+x` - это право не на выполнение, а на получение метаданных файлов и установку директории в качестве рабочей, что фактически и происходит при попытке в директорию *зайти* файловым менеджером, например.

Comment: Нет, `x` это именно право на работу внутри директории. Для чисто список файлов `r` достаточно. Другое дело что больше ничего полезного с этим списком сделать нельзя, даже посмотреть свойства файлов.

Comment: Мда, ну я даю... Пошел читать про chmod...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fQGiDMf2 как тут видно список файлов bash успешно получил

Comment: @AlexeyTen - уточнил формулировку, спасибо!